# Is it reasonable to use Skype for Linux Beta?

Tags: skype

I heard that Skype 4.3 will not work anymore starting from beginning of July 2017. Is it reasonable to switch to the new Skype for Linux Beta?

Is there some Ubuntu package repository for Skype for Linux Beta, or is it recommendable to just install the `*.deb` package from the Skype website? Can Skype for Linux Beta be installed in parallel with the old Skype 4.3?

How well does Skype work with the GNOME desktop? The [Skype for Linux Beta announcement](https://blogs.skype.com/news/2017/03/01/the-skype-for-linux-beta-version-5-0-is-now-available-for-download/) talks about integration with Unity. Does Skype integrate correspondingly with GNOME? Do things break under GNOME?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skype 4.3 will probably stop working soon. Microsoft already extended its life once ;-). So I am not quite sure this will happen in the beginning of July this time.

You can install the deb. A repo will be connected automatically, so you will get updates.

You can install it in parallel with the existing Skype 4.3.

Beware that the beta is incompatible with Skype for Linux 4.3. You will not be able to connect people using the old Skype version on Linux.

Regarding how reasonable it is, it is up to you and opinion based.

Things don't "break" on GNOME. I am using Skype 5.x on unity, gnome and xfce.